# PowerShell - Como criar um sub-site no Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

Tenho um site e preciso criar sub-sites de forma dinâmica pois são muitos clientes e eu tentei usar o powershell pra isso, mas só consigo criar um site collection. Exemplo:

```
new-SPOSite -url httl://url.sharepoint.com/douglas -owner douglas@url.com.br
```

Isso ele cria meu site tudo certo mas preciso criar sub-sites, exemplo:

```
httl://url.sharepoint.com/douglas/cliente1
httl://url.sharepoint.com/douglas/cliente2
httl://url.sharepoint.com/douglas/cliente3
httl://url.sharepoint.com/douglas/cliente4
```

Dessa forma ele não funciona e não consigo achar uma explicação ou meio de fazer isso. Criar manualmente está fora de questão pois são muitos clientes e chegam cada vez mais solicitações para isso.

Ainda não encontrei solução nem no google. Alguém pode dar uma ajuda?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Não e possivel:
http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/168523.aspx

> Managing sub sites with PowerShell is not available in SharePoint Online, and the current PowerShell cmdlets are almost for site collections

Comment: +1. Agora, até onde sei, Powershell para SharePoint Online é um trabalho em andamento. Espero que futuramente isso seja possível.

Answer (score 1):

Duas coisas:

- Se você puder deixar os seus clientes criarem sites, talvez facilite as coisas pra você. Basta o pessoal ter a permissão de Gerenciar Hierarquia na coleção de sites. Daí nas configurações do site raiz eles podem criar os filhos (em *Site Administration -> Sites and Workspaces*).

**Edição:** Depois de ver a resposta do Sunstreaker, percebi que você está usando um comando para criação de coleção de sites. Para criar subsites o comando correto é [`New-SPWeb`](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ff607579%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

- Se o objetivo é que os sites sejam criados sem que o pessoal tenha qualquer acesso à raiz da coleção, você pode criar um script que aceite parâmetros.

Crie um arquivo de extensão `.ps1` com algo do tipo:

```
$endereco = $args[0]
$titulo = $args[1]

new-SPWeb -url $endereco -name $titulo
```

Daí você chama ele assim, do prompt, estando na pasta onde o arquivo se encontra (supondo que o arquivo se chame `foo.ps1`):

```
powershell.exe foo.ps1 "httl://url.sharepoint.com/douglas/clienteBar" "Site do Bar"
```

Ou você pode fazer um programa em .NET em dois minutos que fique gerando e executando essas chamadas ;)

Comment: Oi Renan. Acabei respondendo na resposta do Sunstreaker e tb serve para o que você falou. Não sei como proceder já que o Shell que conecta no Sharepoint Online não é o mesmo.

Comment: @Douglas deve ser só o caso de chamar o executável correspondente ao shell do SharePoint Online, não?

Comment: Na verdade não pois o Shell específico para o Sharepoint Online não tem muitos cmdlets, apenas básicos para gerenciamento... o que eu estou vendo agora é fazer algo com rest pelo powershell... achei que pudesse ser mais fácil que isso.

Answer (score 0):

Acabou que por powershell eu mesmo não consegui e troquei para script onde consigo criar tantos quantos e da forma que preciso cada subsite. Obrigado pelas respostas.